# Is it possible to cancel a delete request for a node or media item?

Tags: 8, hooks

I am trying to create a soft delete method and I was hoping to manipulate cores delete method. The plan was to set a flag on the entity to say that it had been deleted and gets moved to a new page for approval before permanently being deleted.

I am aware there are several contrib modules out there but they are either only in beta or don't quite do what I wanted.

I have been trying to use hook_entity_pre_delete() to set this flag, but I am unable to then cancel the request to delete the entity.

Does anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: I'd go `for hook_form_alter` to add some custom form validation.

Comment: On form level there is already a confirm dialog for entities. In this hook the only way to cancel is I think to throw an exception, which you can catch in an event subscriber to set a redirect to a new page.

Comment: Have you considered the new Content moderation module in core? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/content-moderation/overview

Comment: @IsmailCherri You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: @mpdonadio ok done :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the new [Content Moderation module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/content-moderation/overview) in core? It should provide the desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its a nice idea but this doesn't seem to do anything to stop the node being deleted :(